# how to create website builder in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dhtml, dhtmlx

I have seen an application somewhere that creates dynamic pages. You can select different table layouts and add your user control with drag and drop and just save. 
How can we create this facility in asp.net?

Comment: what ? i didn't get you ?  Quentin

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking *specific* programming questions, you are asking for instructions on how to build a complete (and complicated) application.

Comment: yah previously i write that but after some time i changes question because no one visit my question.

Comment: Take a look at [dropthings](http://code.google.com/p/dropthings/).  It's an open source project that allows users to heavily customize and personalize their own pages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the GridView control.  There are absolutely tons of examples of this on the web, try starting here (the ASP.net 2.0 examples are more basic, which will probably be useful if you're just starting out): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

Comment: no dear i am not looking for GridView , i am working in asp.net from 6 years and i am finding this facility to create dynamic page like site builder.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you're calling me "dear".  Despite that, ASP.NET 2.0 had GridView and ASP.NET 1.1 had DataGrid.  Both of those are more than 6 years old, so you can use either to create a quick simple CRUD type application.

Comment: yah but data grid is not a solution for that, i seen it and they use DHTML too for create page and you can see page live how it i will look like in that application. its same as site builder but dynamic.

Comment: @Milimetric - From past conversations, I think its that some people from the sub-continent noticed that we westerners address letters "Dear Mr Jones..." and think this is an acceptable salutation outside of formal letter writing.

Comment: @Jamiec oh that makes sense :)  I was pretty sure it was not intended in a mean way but it can be taken as condescending in some cases.